# libc++.dylib was built for newer macOS version, what should I do?

Tags: xcode, macos, linker-errors

I am using plain old **make** to build a macOS executable. After some upgrade, I see

```
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/lib/libc++.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (13.2) than being linked (13.0)
```

The easy fix is to add **`-mmacosx-version-min=13.2`** to **LDFLAGS**, but this will probably backfire with the next upgrade. It's not that I can't find the version programmatically:

```
otool -l /usr/local/lib/libc++.dylib | grep minos | awk '{print $2}'
```

The question is why this happens to me in the first place. I have the latest Xcode 14.3.1 installed, which declares support for macOS 13.3. And another question: if I want my executable to be run also on macOS Ventura 13.0, do I need to build it with Xcode 14.1 (or command-line tools of the same old version)? Or it's enough to set **`-mmacosx-version-min=13.0`**?

Answer (score 1):

The warning you're seeing indicates that the library `/usr/local/lib/libc++.dylib` was built for a newer version of macOS (13.2) than the one you're currently linking against (13.0). This warning typically occurs when you have a mix of library versions on your system, and it's trying to link against a library that is not compatible with the target macOS version.

To address the warning, you can add the `-mmacosx-version-min=13.2` flag to the LDFLAGS, as you mentioned. This flag tells the linker to set the minimum macOS version that your executable will be compatible with. By setting it to 13.2, you ensure that the linker doesn't complain about the libc++ library being built for a newer version.

Regarding your concern about the next upgrade causing potential issues with the specific macOS version, it's difficult to predict future upgrades and their impact. However, it's generally a good practice to keep your development environment up to date, including Xcode and the command-line tools, to ensure compatibility with the latest macOS versions. This way, you can benefit from the latest features and bug fixes provided by Apple.

If you want your executable to be compatible with macOS Ventura 13.0, you have a couple of options:

Set the minimum macOS version to 13.0: You can use the `-mmacosx-version-min=13.0` flag when compiling and linking your code. This will ensure that your executable is compatible with macOS 13.0 and newer versions.

Test on macOS Ventura 13.0: To ensure compatibility, it's recommended to test your executable on a macOS Ventura 13.0 system, either through physical hardware or virtual machines. This way, you can verify that your application runs as expected on the target platform.

Note that setting the minimum macOS version to 13.0 doesn't mean your executable won't run on newer macOS versions. It only ensures compatibility with the specified minimum version while allowing it to run on newer releases as well.

Ultimately, it's essential to test your application on the target platform(s) you intend to support and verify its compatibility with the specific macOS versions you're targeting.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. Unfortunately, this does not explain why the warning happens now (why the version of clang++.dylib is not compatible with my clang++), or what I can do to ensure that they are in sync in the future. As for forcing `-mmacosx-version-min=13.0`, I am afraid this will not work, because the dylib on the target  machine will be older than the one used for build.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  I received an extremely similar answer back from ChatGPT when asking this question. Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thanks for checking against ChatGPT. It looks quite probable that the answer was assisted by AI, because it feels too talkative and does not answer my specific questions. OTOH, was this the reason for the flagging the question as *This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline*?

Comment: @AlexCohn Usually we'd flag this with "In need of moderator attention" and explain that we felt it was AI-generated and why.  However, at the moment, flagging won't have any effect due to (a) the SE policy changes on how this is handled, and (b) the resulting Strike by moderators (and community members).  In the meantime, I'm simply posting comments to make sure that (1) users who post this content are aware of the policy, (2) readers are aware that it likely came from AI and should be closely reviewed.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).